# how to iterate through html recieved via jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax which returns some html as data.

```
success: function(data){
$('#ajaxresponse ul.display li input').each(function(index) {
```

ajax response is a div which comes from jquery ajax success data. How to get the html from the response?

Comment: `$(data).find('ul.display li input')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find()` method in jQuery

```
success: function(data){
$(data).find('#ajaxresponse ul.display li input').each(function(index) {
  ........................
});
```

Documentation:[**http://api.jquery.com/find/**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: i think #ajaxresponse is the wrapping element returned by ajax request but anyway +1

Comment: @A.Wolff : that may depend upon his response , I can't make any prediction :)

Answer (score 0):

you can append it to your html DOM where your want it to go, then do as you do now:

```
success: function(data){
$("#YourDiv").after(returnValue);
$('#ajaxresponse ul.display li input').each(function(index) {
```

where returnValue is a var containing the data returned by your ajax

Comment: Don't need to append. See Pranav Ram's answer.